# Integrate slack message menu with DialogFlow

Tags: slack-api, dialogflow-es

I am working on a Chatbot for Slack with DialogFlow. I have put a message menu in Slack. I want to send the selected value to DialogFlow as an intent. It does not work.
Does DialogFlow supports message menus or Do I have to setup a webhook myself?

Thanks.

Comment: You need a server, in middle.
Add server to dialogflow, parse request object, convert to slack compatible object.

Comment: If I do that I have to parse myself the quick replies button that are working now. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@praveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6885735/praveen-soni) suggested you will need to `enable Fulfilment` in DialogFlow settings for the project and `point it to your fulfilment back-end service`. After you have done that check [Rich Messages Doc](https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages)  to see what data payload to respond with to DialogFlow from your Fulfilment service to make Slack display a menu.

**UPDATE**

If you want to perform an action in Slack and enable Slack notify you of that action then you can either user Slack RTM or [Slack's event API](https://api.slack.com/events-api)

Comment: Indeed, I have already a webhook which handles the display of the menu in Slack. My problem is that when a user select a field, the value is not sent as an intent to DialogFlow

Comment: Check the In-context for the intent that you want to match, it is possible that the required context is not in scope, so it doesn't match the desired intent.

Comment: I have looked for that and it is ok. Even if the intent doesn't match, I should have the input.unknown to be triggered and it is not the case.

Comment: @VidushanChooriyakumaran, check the update that i made to the answer.